# accessing crm changes via odata

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am using odata to query Dynamics CRM Online 2013. I am trying to track changes against particular entities. For example, I want to be able to see Old Values and New Values for Opportunities, as you would see in the Summary View. Auditing is enabled for the entities but the most I can see via odata is whether a field of an entity was changed or not, and when it was changed.

Q. If "Change Tracking" is enabled will that expose another odata entity that will give me those changed values?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure Audit entity data is not exposed via OData.

Comment: Want to share what I learnt today: https://yanivrdt.wordpress.com/2016/01/08/retrieving-audit-history-records-via-api/

Answer (score 0):

Please find the url for the actual usage of Change Tracking feature.
http://www.powerobjects.com/2015/10/26/change-tracking-in-dynamics-crm-2015/

Answer (score 0):

Audit table is not consumable through Sdk calls.. neither odata nor soap.
On premise will allow to query using sql queries but still data is "," "~" separated.

On the other hand Change tracking is accessible through sdk call using RetrieveEntityChangesRequest message. Pls refer the link below.

But this is for primary usage of integration services to identify the modified records for upstream/downstream systems from last cycle.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932130.aspx

**Update**: Reg Audit, we have some limited options though - https://yanivrdt.wordpress.com/2016/01/08/retrieving-audit-history-records-via-api/